# Compare arrays of sub-string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How can I check if an array of strings contains part of words stored in another array of strings ?

Let's say I've declared these three arrays :

```js
array1 = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor" "sit" "amet"]

array2 = ["Lorem", "ipsum"]

keywords = ["ipsum", "dol"]
```

When comparing `array1` with `keywords`, I want to get something like `true` because `"ipsum"` and `"dol"` are in `array1`, but `false`, when comparing `array2` with `keywords` because `"dol"` isn't in `array2`

I searched for an hour, but I don't know how to do it... I succeeded to compare arrays with one keyword, but not with several keywords.

Comment: Should keywords be `["ipsum", "dolor"]`? (dol -> dolor)

Comment: Keywords should be words like `ipsum` or part of words like just `ipsu`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For every element in keywords array (use `.every()`)
- There must be some element in other array (use `.some()`)
- That includes the string currently in consideration (use `.includes()`)

**Demo:**

```js
let array1   = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"],
    array2   = ["Lorem", "ipsum"],
    keywords = ["ipsum", "dol"];

let compare = (a, k) => k.every(s => a.some(v => v.includes(s)));

console.log(compare(array1, keywords));
console.log(compare(array2, keywords));
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: Do you need the some?

Comment: @AndrewBone yes, without some how we will find a match between keyword item and any element in other array?

Comment: Thank you @MohammadUsman, it helps me a lot !!! I try to do it before asking the question, but I use 2 loops and it wasn't really clean ^^

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.every`

```
let contains = keywords.every(k => array1.findIndex(a => a.indexOf(k) > -1) > -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayContains(array1,array2){
 var res=0;
 for (var i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
  for (var j=0;i<array2.length;j++){
    if (array1[i]==array2[j])
        res++
   } 
 }
 return res==array2.length//if res is eqaul to array2.length then all elements of array2 are inside array1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `indexOf` instead of `includes` as `includes` do not work in IE browsers. [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility)

```js
let array1   = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"],
    array2   = ["Lorem", "ipsum"],
    keywords = ["ipsum", "dol"];

let compare = (a, k) => k.every(s => a.some(v => v.indexOf(s) !== -1));

console.log(compare(array1, keywords));
console.log(compare(array2, keywords));
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip ;)

Comment: If not mistaken, arrow functions do not work in IE browsers as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
var array1 = ['a','b','c'];
var array2 = ['g','f','h'];

var keys = ['a','g'];

function checkIfExists(key, arr) {
   if (arr.indexOf(key) != -1) {
     console.log('Key ' + key + ' exists in array');
   } else {
     console.log('Key ' + key + ' does not exists in array');
   } 

}

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    checkIfExists(keys[i], array1);
}

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    checkIfExists(keys[i], array2);
}
```

Output :

Key a exists in array
Key g does not exists in array
Key a does not exists in array
Key g exists in array

Comment: I wrote  `keywords.every(k => array1.indexOf(k) > -1)`, but it works only when the keyword is the full word, i want to have also part of word