# Check value is equal to specific value in an array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, conditional-statements

I have the below object

```
members
    {
        [
            age:30,
            list: [
                "PRICE",
                "LIST",
                "COUNTRY"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        [
            age:31,
            list: [
                "PRICE"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        [
            age:31,
            list: [
                "LIST"
            ]
        ]
    }
```

I need to check if array values are equal to specific value.

I need to check if `list` has `PRICE` or `list` has `COUNTRY` or `list` has `PRICE,LIST,COUNTRY` combination.

Currently I'm using `includes` which checks if value is present. But i need to check exact value

```
Array.isArray(members.list.map(message, index){
        if(message.includes("LIST"))
        {

        }
        if(message.includes("PRICE"))
        {

        }
         if(message.includes("PRICE") && message.includes("LIST") && message.includes("COUNTRY"))
        {
            //message.includes("PRICE") and ("LIST") is already executed, so this will execute again. But i need to execute the complete condition combination.
        }
    })
```

How to acheive this?

Comment: `Array.isArray(members.list.map(...))` makes not that much sense as `.map()` will always return an array O.o

Comment: Check this post, it can help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101635/compare-arrays-of-sub-string)

Comment: @Andreas so what should be the solution?

Comment: Turn the comparison to have the most specific first, then use else: `if(message.includes("PRICE") && message.includes("LIST") && message.includes("COUNTRY")) {}
else if(message.includes("LIST")) {}
  else if(message.includes("PRICE")) { }`

Comment: @siraxtas but that post does not show about checking combination

Comment: What do you mean with 'But i need to check exact value'. If the array contains price and country... you don't want to return true because it's none of the combinations? Or is it OK, because price is present? Can you please clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is to loop through all possible `if` condition. 
So you shouldn't do `return` within a condition checking. 
You can save the result and override it whenever it matches a condition. Hope can help. 
Also there is some problem of your origin members Object. Also fixed in the following demo.

```js
let members = [
 { age: 30, list: ["PRICE", "LIST", "COUNTRY"] },
 { age: 31, list: ["PRICE"] },
 { age: 31, list: ["LIST"] }
];

   Array.prototype.inArray = function () {
var message = this;
if (message.includes("PRICE") && message.includes("LIST") && message.includes("COUNTRY")) {
 return "contains PRICE, LIST and COUNTRY";
}
if (message.includes("PRICE") && message.includes("LIST") ) {
 return "contains PRICE and LIST ";
}
if (message.includes("PRICE") &&  message.includes("COUNTRY")) {
 return "contains PRICE and COUNTRY";
}
if (message.includes("LIST") && message.includes("COUNTRY")) {
 return "contains LIST and COUNTRY";
}
if (message.includes("LIST")) {
 return "contains LIST";
}
if (message.includes("PRICE")) {
 return "contains PRICE";
}
if (message.includes("LIST")) {
 return "contains LIST";
}
}

for (let member of members) {
 console.log(member.list.inArray());
}
```

Comment: I want either `PRICE` or `PRICE, LIST, COUNTRY` combination to execute..  In your code, both will execute

Comment: Sorry that i have misunderstand your question. The most stupid solution are as the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can compose a filter function and use that for Array.prototype.filter

```js
const members = [
  {
    age: 30,
    list: ["PRICE","LIST","COUNTRY"]
  },
  {
    age: 31,
    list: ["PRICE"]
  },
  {
    age: 31,
    list: ["LIST"]
  },
  {
    age: 88,
    list: ["not this one"]
  },
  {
    age: 88,
    list: ["not this one","COUNTRY","NOTPRICEORLIST"]
  }
]

const getList = o => (o&&o.list) || [];//get list member from o or returns empty array
const contains = needle => haystack => haystack.includes(needle);//check if haystack contains needle
const containsAll = needles => haystack => needles.reduce(
  (result,needle)=>result && haystack.includes(needle),
  true
);
const countryOrPriceOrPriceListCountry = haystack =>
  contains("PRICE")(haystack) || contains("LIST")(haystack)
  //this is pointless, would already be true because it contains price or country
  // || containsAll(["PRICE","LIST","COUNTRY"])(haystack);

const filter = getter => comparer => item =>//get something from item (list) and send to compare function
  comparer(getter(item));

console.log(
  members.filter(filter(getList)(countryOrPriceOrPriceListCountry))
);
```

Or maybe you were looking for the following:

```js
const members = [
  {
    age: 30,
    list: ["PRICE","LIST","COUNTRY"]
  },
  {
    age: 31,
    list: ["PRICE"]
  },
  {
    age: 32,
    list: ["LIST"]
  },
  {
    age: 88,
    list: ["not this one"]
  },
  {
    age: 89,
    list: ["not this one","COUNTRY","NOTPRICEORLIST"]
  }
]

const getList = o => (o&&o.list) || [];//get list member from o or returns empty array
const contains = needle => haystack => haystack.includes(needle);//check if haystack contains needle
const containsAll = needles => haystack => needles.reduce(
  (result,needle)=>result && haystack.includes(needle),
  true
);
const countryOrPrice = haystack =>
  contains("PRICE")(haystack) || contains("LIST")(haystack)
const countryListAndPrice = containsAll(["PRICE","LIST","COUNTRY"]);

members.map(
  item=>[item,countryOrPrice(getList(item))]//see if item has country or price
).map(
  ([item,hasCountryOrPrice])=>[
    item,
    hasCountryOrPrice,
    // will check for country list and price only if has country or price 
    hasCountryOrPrice && countryListAndPrice(getList(item))
  ]
).forEach(
  ([item,hasCountryOrPrice,countryListAndPrice])=>
    console.log(
      "item age:",
      item.age,
      "has country or price:",
      hasCountryOrPrice,
      "has country list and price:",
      countryListAndPrice
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```js
var members = [
 { age: 30, list: ["PRICE", "LIST", "COUNTRY"] },
 { age: 31, list: ["PRICE"] },
 { age: 31, list: ["LIST"] }
];
members.forEach((val,key)=>{
 if(Array.isArray(val.list)){
  if(val.list.indexOf('PRICE') > -1 || val.list.indexOf('COUNTRY') > -1 || (val.list.indexOf('PRICE') > -1 && val.list.indexOf('COUNTRY') > -1 && val.list.indexOf('LIST') > -1)){
   console.log(val)
  }
 }
});
```